# VSCode, how to drag down terminal when I pulled it too high

Tags: ide, editor

[image: vscode terminal fills window]

Do I have to restart?  The mouse pointer does not change at all when I go to the top where, if my memory serves me correctly, the cursor changes and I can drag the terminal window size down smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `v` next to `x` on the title bar of the terminal screen.

Comment: I did that and clicked `Configure Terminal Settings`, went in and scrolled the settings, did not change anything and somewhere in between the terminal was resized smaller (shorter).